# typescript import doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, electron

I'm trying to solve this problem is already more than 6-8 hours. 
I think one of the problems is my english. =)

I use atom editor, electron, typescript, react

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "isolatedModules": false,
        "jsx": "react",
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "declaration": false,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "noImplicitUseStrict": false,
        "removeComments": true,
        "noLib": false,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "typings/browser",
        "typings/browser.d.ts"
    ],
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "buildOnSave": false,
    "atom": {
        "rewriteTsconfig": false
    }
}
```

**app.ts:**

```
import {hello} from "./func";
hello("TypeScript");
```

**func.ts**

```
export function hello(name: string){
    console.log(`Hello, ${name}`);
}
```

**Start electron and get error:**

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

then, create file **react-test.ts:**

```
import * as React from "react";
```

**get error in atom editor:**

```
Cannot find module 'react'
```

**Question:**
I do not want more theory. There is a specific example. Please help me to solve it. By the way I did not have any problem with babel =)

**Update #1:**

**Electron run command:**

```
npm start
```

Project on [github](https://github.com/imsory/ts-import)

Comment: It could be a number of different problems, we would need more information to know what the problem is. Specifically, how are you running electron? How are you running tsc? What does this have to do with electron? What does your index.html file look like? What does your `package.json` file look like?

Comment: i just found an example import file and tried to implement it. Electron run command `npm start`, github [link](https://github.com/imsory/ts-import). Its just  electron quick start example + typescript + react + redux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to transpile TypeScript to JavaScript with `tsc` command and in `index.html` file require `app.js` instead `app.ts`. Then run Electron with `npm start`

Comment: Nice! Finally, i understood the concept and found a good example here [link](https://github.com/claudioc/electron-typescript-react-quick-start). Spasibo Misha! =)

Comment: @user3650075 I am glad it helped!